# How to stop make -jN consuming too much memory?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I have a build where if I use `make -j2` it completes in say 20mins.

If I use `make -j3` it completes in 15mins. However sometimes with `make -j3` the compiler crashes because too much system memory is used. Is there a way to tell the compiler to limit its instances when memory is low to prevent this?

Comment: I've encountered the same problem as well. I doubt there will be a way, though. This feature sounds complicated. How would make know how much RAM they will consume before-hand?

Comment: If it's the compiler that's consuming too much memory then this isn't anything to do with make.  You'll have to look at your compiler flags to see if there are any that control memory usage.  Offhand I'm not aware of any but I've never looked specifically for that.  You should be sure to _not_ use the `-pipe` flag; other than that I don't know.

Comment: @sashoalm impossible I suppose, perhaps they could catch out of memory signals and have an option to re-try rather than just fail? Or when they see very little memory left and N compiler/linker instances running then wait for some to finish?

Comment: Did you try to limit the address space or heap data using `ulimit`, that is `setrlimit`? AFAIK, some compilers just switch off some optimizations when `malloc` is failing.

Comment: I've never had that issue, even with make -j8 (a point at which probably even on a 4 core machine with hyperthreading the overhead starts to outgrow the benefits). Can you tell us more about the program you are "making"? Are you sure it's the gcc using the memory or are you perhaps performing some other processing? Are there particularly large source files, or unusual options, like inlining with large maximum function lengths or such (look for "exponential" and "non-linear" in the gcc manual)?

Comment: How much memory do you have? What machine? Swap is on? gcc version (may not be that important, but who knows)? Generally any up-to-date PC should be able to handle three gcc instances at the same time. After all, we run MS word on it. Or, probably worse, OpenOffice on Linux.

Comment: Its running on a Travis-CI machine, specs are: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#The-Build-Machine, compiler version is "g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04) 4.9.2" with make -j2 I never have these failures, with -j3 I get random compiler crashes

Comment: Ah, 3 GB is less than usual on dedicated hardware these days. That explains part of the story. Still plenty for plain compilation though.

Comment: Are you sure it is a compilation that crashes, and not some test cases?

Comment: Its the compiler: g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I expect the compiler does not ALWAYS understand why some pointer is NULL, so some code that does `return createsomething(...);` and since it does that, it can't check the result from `createsomething`, which did the `malloc` and that returned `NULL`. Unfortunately not something you can easily fix other than "run lower -j" or "give the machine more memory" [which of course may mean that you don't get so many virtual machines, so which is better of that and "run lower -j" is probably the subject best left for some experimenting]

Comment: You can use `/bin/time -v make <args>` to measure how much memory you need for a particular build.

Comment: Ah, "killed" will be the OOM killer. Add more memory or swap. If you can't ... don't do that then.

Comment: Note also that the compiler isn't what determines the number of instances, that is done by `make`. And `make` has little understanding of what the compiler actually requires to compile a particular source-file - that would pretty much require compiling the code first, since there is no obvious way to tell without at least parsing the code.

Comment: I suppose you could write a wrapper that takes any command as its arguments, executes it, but stops it (kill -STOP) as soon as its memory consumption is past a given limit, and the total memory consumption is also past a given limit; and continues (kill -CONT) it as soon as total memory consumption has gone down. Then you could change the `SHELL` variable to that command.

Comment: You could also have such a thing running as a permanent background process, and make it select only invocations of the compiler to work on.

Answer (score 1):

[`GNU parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) can be used to start tasks depending on a large number of criteria, one of them being sufficient free memory left.